# Discord JS attachment

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

What im trying to do is basically let the bot upload the .db file on discord.

what i tried:

```
if(cmd == "backup"){
  message.channel.send(moment().format('YYYY/MM/D hh:mm:ss SSS'),{files:['./data/db.db']})
}
```

which would just send the formatted date without the file, and then i tried:

```
if(cmd == "backup"){
  const file = new MessageAttachment('./data/db.db')
  message.channel.send(file)
}
```

which would just give an error of an empty message.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(cmd == "backup"){
  const moment = require('moment')
  message.channel.send({content: "> DB backup: "+moment().format('YYYY/MM/D hh:mm:ss SSS'), files: [
    { attachment: './data/db.db' }
]})
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This answer falls a little short of our advice on [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Can you add some description about how you solved the problem; resources used, etc., and how it differs from your original solution? Thanks!